# Retrieving Email knowing its ID

Tags: c#, interop, outlook, message

I'm making a prog in C#, a part of it need to select a Mail Message using
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook objects..

i really need help with this..

i already know the Email ID, anyone has a suggestion, would be very appreciated, thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve data from a mail message, it looks like you will need to access the Outlook folder on your harddrive within your code. [Here is an article](http://geekswithblogs.net/TimH/archive/2006/05/26/79720.aspx) explaining how.

Comment: no not locally, i'll explain
my prog creates an appointment, so before sending it i should get the ID and store it in a table,
later, using that id i should have the possibility of cancel the appointment.
any ideas THANKS guys

Comment: Based on my experience with this I cannot help you much further. If you add more detail to your question then I am sure others will be more inclined to help!